# Submit button is not working in FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I have been trying to make a `FormGroup`, but I have a question. The submit button is not working. What would be the cause for this? **create** is the name of the component in my project.

**create.component.html**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addPost(postsForm.value)" [formGroup]="postsForm">
  <p>full the form</p>

  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName="title" />

  <label for="content">content</label>
  <textarea formControlName="content"></textarea>

  <label for="cover" class="cover">choose a file</label>
  <input
    type="file"
    name="cover"
    id="cover"
    (change)="handleInput(event)"
    formControlName="cover"
  />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**create.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DesignService } from '../design.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'ngx-create',
    templateUrl: './create.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./create.component.scss']
})

export class CreateComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private service: DesignService) {}

    image: any = null;

    public postForm = new FormGroup({
        title: new FormControl(''),
        content: new FormControl(''),
        cover: new FormControl('')
    });

    public handleInput($event: Event) {
        alert('handlse');
        this.image = $event.target['files'];
    }

    public addPost(data: FormData) {
        alert('this is add post');
        this.service.createPost(data, this.image);
    }

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

My intention is call `addPost()` function after clicking the `submit` button. Can you help me?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, just an FYI. You don't need to pass the form value in from your template. You can just do `(ngSubmit)="addPost()"` then in your component.ts do `this.service.createPost(this.postForm.value, this.image);`

Comment: `<input type="submit" value="Submit" />` inside the `create.component.html`

Comment: There is a typo!! Use `postForm` instead of `postsForm`. Here you go: `<form (ngSubmit)="addPost(postForm.value)" [formGroup]="postForm">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your code

In your html, You are using

`[formGroup]="postsForm"`

It should be

`[formGroup]="postForm"`

Also you need to change it while passing to `addPost` function

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create a `formGroup` with name `postForm`

```
    public postForm = new FormGroup({
       title: new FormControl(''),
       content: new FormControl(''),
       cover: new FormControl('')
    });
```

and in the html you use the name `postsForm`

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addPost(postsForm.value)" [formGroup]="postsForm">
```

Change one of them,and the problem is fixed.